# How do you correct the path separators in git when using powershell

Tags: git, powershell

I'm using the github powershell addon to run git on windows.  Everything seems to work fine except for when I'm adding submodules.  In this case, the powershell addon is adding in paths with `\\` as path separators instead of `/`.

Example

```
[submodule "lib\\myLibrary"]
    path = lib\\myLibrary
    url = path\to\library\repository
```

If I go in and manually correct the path separators, I can successfully run 'git submodule update --init' and get the submodule as expected.